# How to properly pass data to a submodule and get results back in verilog?

Tags: verilog

Say I have a submodule and want to "call" it from a top module.

[image: picture]

```
//sub.v
module sub(
    input wire clk,
    input wire rst_n,
    input wire update,//interface is modifiable
    input wire [7:0] in_data,
    output wire[7:0] out_data
);

reg[7:0] state;

always @(posedge clk) begin
    if(!rst_n)
        state<=0;
    else if(update)
        state<=state+in_data;//update drives states to change according to input data
end

assign out_data=state<<1;

endmodule
```

```
//top.v
module top(
    input wire clk,
    input wire rst_n,
    output reg[7:0] top_out
);

//Submodule
reg sub_update;
reg[7:0] sub_in;
wire[7:0] sub_out;

sub sub_instance(
    .clk(clk),
    .rst_n(rst_n),
    .update(sub_update),
    .in_data(sub_in),
    .out_data(sub_out)
);

//Topmodule
reg[7:0] top_state;
localparam STATE0       = 8'd0;
localparam STATE1       = 8'd1;
localparam STATE2       = 8'd2;
localparam STATE3       = 8'd3;
localparam TEMP_STATE   = -8'd1;
always @(posedge clk) begin
    if(!rst_n) begin
        top_state   <=  STATE0;
        sub_update  <=  0;
        sub_in      <=  0;
    end else begin
        case (top_state)
        STATE0:top_state<=STATE1;
        STATE1:begin
            //want to update the submodule and use its output here
            sub_in      <=  123;
            sub_update  <=  1;
            top_state   <=  TEMP_STATE;
        end
        STATE2:top_state<=STATE3;//proceed from STATE1
        TEMP_STATE:begin
            sub_update  <=  0;
            top_out     <=  sub_out+1;
            top_state   <=  STATE2;
        end
        default:top_state<=STATE0;
        endcase
    end
end

endmodule
```

The main question may divide into 2 smaller questions:

1. In my module code, the "update" signal is both set and captured at the same edge of a same clock. Is that a data race? Should I use a different edge, or pass a reverse clock to the submodule? Or should I change "update" to other interface?
2. Is there a better way to get the submodule output than using a temporary state? For this simple example, there is a way to calculate the output when the input is ready: Inline everything, get `top_out<=((state+123)<<1)+1;` at STATE1. Can this be generalized for more complicated calculation?

Answer (score 0):

1. there is no problem in setting and capturing 'update' on the same clock edge. Just note that it will be captured with a delay of one clock cycle after it is set. This is the way flops work and your simulation should work same way because you did correctly use NBAs.
2. This is the question that you should answer for yourself. Better ways or not depend on your requirements and abilities of hardware. You have all these parts of the equation and states for some reason. You can probably collapse them if your algorithm allows it. You can use complex calculations there if they do not violate your design rules.

Comment: Thanks! So the top module doesn't get the correct return value at TEMP_STATE. It should wait for another clock cycle, right? Is reversing clk a good idea since it saves one clock?

Comment: you did not explain what 'correct' means. You should run your simulation and get results. Then you can figure out if they differ from what you expect and try to debug, if they are. If stuck, ask a question.